# Bash script monitor file modification after its closed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

It has already been asked here and I have found the solution for the first part of my question. So for the moment I have a bash script (*script1*) where I evaluate the sha1sum of a specific file (*output.dat*) periodically (lets say every 1 sec). When the `sha1sum_cur != sha1sum_prev` then I run another script (*script2*) with some commands. Meaning this way that the file has modified.

My problem is that *output.dat* is quite a lot MBs and takes quite long to be written. So, I dont want to run *script2* while data are being written to it, but after the process of writing data to it has finished. *output.dat* is being created by a fortran code, so lets say every 1h it deletes previous data and writes new ones but takes around 5min for that.

two last important notes: 
1) Since I am submitting my jobs to a cluster, i dont have the permission to install inotify-tools. 
2) I could call the script through the fortran code, once I `close(output.txt)` with `CALL system(./script2)` but I would rather not do so, since its parallel and don't want to slow down its efficiency.

So the question is, what I could add to *script1* so that it understands that the process of writing data to *output.dat* has finished?

Comment: You don't need to install inotify-tools into the system, you can just build it in you home directory and run it from this place.

Comment: Indeed llay that can be done, i was thinking though of a more portable script, not depending on other tools/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **lsof** to check if any process is accessing that file. However, this would not protect against other process changing the file *after* you've checked for access in you shell script.

To avoid race conditions, I'd use atomic file operations, like **mv**, to mark that your shell script or other software has not 'picked up' the file. This is a kernel call and is guaranteed to be atomic (as in, if two processes call mv on the same file at the same time, one will succeed and the other will fail).

Another possibility is to use an external locking tool like **lockfile-progs**, but those you can't use from you software that drop the file. *mv* is universal, although an arguably dirty solution.